# How to disable a particular dbus system service under an openrc system

Tags: linux, services, d-bus, software-updates, openrc

I know that one can override dbus **session** services in `~/.local/share/dbus-1/services`

But it necessarily won't work for **system** services.

**Under openrc**, I don't get systemd's systemctl command therefore :

Is the quick and dirty (because service will be restored on next update) way consisting in renaming the associated service file in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services`, the only way to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered this same problem, and after digging into the dbus code, I think I have a solution:

Files in `/usr/local/share/dbus-1/system-services` override the files in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services`. So, to prevent a service from autostarting, you can create an empty file. For example, to make sure dbus never starts login1 automatically:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/dbus-1/system-services
touch /usr/local/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.login1.service
```

This also allows you to disable user services globally using `/usr/local/share/dbus-1/services`.

Another effective method to prevent it from launching services by itself is building dbus with `-Dtraditional_activation=false`. However, this disables all services.

Comment: Whoa ! This just makes sense. So immediately +1 for that info. I was still waiting for an answer to this problem. I make no doubt it should work since I just verified that updates don't touch /usr/local but I'll test your suggestion asap and if OK will accept your answer, say : splendid! and add a +50 bounty for having shared your work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the D-Bus service have a `SystemdService=` line pointing to a Systemd unit file, like `SystemdService=systemd_unit_name.service`?

If yes, you can add a symlink from `/etc/systemd/system/systemd_unit_name.service` to `/dev/null`. This is how `systemctl mask systemd_unit_name.service` works.

Then any attempt to activate the D-Bus service will fail since the linked Systemd service is masked. But you may see some annoying logs in the journal about a failed activation since the service is masked.

If there is no `SystemdService=` line, you can try adding a symlink from `/etc/systemd/system/dbus_unit_name.service` to `/dev/null` (not tested). I assume if there is no alias mapping from a D-Bus unit file named `dbus_unit_name.service` to a Systemd unit file name `systemd_unit_name.service`, the D-Bus activation will just look for a Systemd unit file with the same name as the D-Bus unit file, like `dbus_unit_name.service`.

You can also override D-Bus system services in `/etc/dbus-1/system-services/`, I believe (again, not tested).

Comment: Thank you for taking car of this problem however you solution presuppose *systemd* thingies I just do not get since, as stated in OP, I am on an systemd-less (openrc) system.